# How to have vue v-if in App.vue - but button with toggle in component?

Tags: vue.js

In my `App.vue` I have a `v-if` that is hiding a div (data is returning false).  I would like to toggle this, however I would like to place the button in another component (which is imported into App.vue).

Thank you for your replies.  I have tried adding props like so:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ButtonBar />
    <div v-if="hamburgers">
      <Hamburgers />
    </div>
    <div v-if="hotdogs">
      <Hotdogs />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ButtonBar from "@/components/buttonbar";
import Hamburgers from "@/components/hamburgers";
import Hotdogs from "@/components/hotdogs";

export default {
  components: {ButtonBar, Hamburgers, Hotdogs},
  props: ['hamburgers', 'hotdogs']
};
</script>
```

Then in the buttonbar component, I have:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button v-on:click="hamburger=!hamburger">Hamburgers</button>
    <button v-on:click="hotdogs=!hotdogs">Hot Dogs</button>
  </div>
<template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
     return {
         hamburgers: false,
         hotdogs: false,
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If that component is used in App.vue then pass `hidden` as a prop.

Comment: Thanks @YashMaheshwari I have attempted a solution based on your reply

Answer (score 0):

I created sample Parent and Child components that implement the functionality you describe.

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <h3>Parent.vue</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div v-if="showDiv">Div for child to show/hide</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <child @toggle-parent-div="toggleDiv" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Child from './Child.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      Child
    },
    data() {
      return {
        showDiv: true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggleDiv() {
        this.showDiv = !this.showDiv;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Child.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
    <hr>
    <h3>Child.vue</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="toggleParentDiv">Click to toggle parent div</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      toggleParentDiv() {
        this.$emit('toggle-parent-div');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```